# KSH script too big to run

Tags: oracle, ksh

I never had a problem like this, but I have a KSH script to insert Oracle rows and the script fails because is too big, I know this is the problem because if y delete a number of inserts, the script works.

The script size is 90.000 kb aprox and the structure is like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s << LABEL1
USER/PasWoRd@10.10.10.10:1234/oraSID

-- Define 3 variables
variable msgVal number;
variable msgeId varchar2(50);
variable msgseqval varchar2(50);

-- 1 Original time: 3/1/2018 12:46:34 AM
EXEC :msgVal := MESSAGEIDSEQ.NextVal;
EXEC :msgeId := CONCAT ('B_',to_char (sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');

INSERT into TABLE_CONTROL (MESSAGE_ID, NUMBER_OF_ROWS, SEND_DATE) VALUES (:msgeId, 1, to_char (sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'));
INSERT into TABLE_DATA(MESSAGE_ID, SHORT_TEXT, LONG_TEXT_FLAG) VALUES (:msgeId,  'SHORT TEXT', 'N');

commit;
EXEC dbms_lock.sleep (30);

-- PFP 2 Original time: 3/1/2018 1:46:25 AM
EXEC :msgseqval := MESSAGEIDSEQ.nextval;
EXEC :msgVal := MESSAGEIDSEQ.NextVal;
EXEC :msgeId := CONCAT (CONCAT (CONCAT ('B_',to_char (sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')), '_'), to_char (:msgVal));
INSERT into TABLE_CONTROL (MESSAGE_ID, NUMBER_OF_ROWS, SEND_DATE) VALUES (:msgeId, 1, to_char (sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'));
INSERT into TABLE_DATA(MESSAGE_ID, SHORT_TEXT, LONG_TEXT_FLAG) VALUES (:msgeId,  'SHORT TEXT', 'N');

commit;
EXEC dbms_lock.sleep (30);

LABEL1
```

But around 200.000 inserts.

I need to run with nohup and I wonder if there is a way to do it in just one script.

Regards.

Luis

Comment: Write it as PL/SQL procedure. What is the reason for `dbms_lock.sleep (30);`?

Comment: Another option is to use external tables, failing that SQL*Loader - plenty of information out there on both

Comment: Where does the insert statements come from and how are they generated?

Comment: Separating the data from the logic sounds like sensible starting point.

Comment: Ok. The data comes from a different environment  We are testing in an isolated environment a free flow cars detection system, we need to simulate every day thousands of cars /tracks/motos crossing the detector. That's why we have the sleep command, to simulate time between cars. Thanks!

Comment: `EXEC :msgseqval := MESSAGEIDSEQ.nextval;` looks superfluous.  Otherwise each section appears very similar, so I assume that these scripts are generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably has something to do with the `sqlplus` input buffer. Why not write your statements and commands to a file and execute it:

```
cat <<LABEL1 >/tmp/foobar
USER/PasWoRd@10.10.10.10:1234/oraSID
...
commit;
EXEC dbms_lock.sleep (30);

LABEL1
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s @/tmp/foobar
rm /tmp/foobar
```